# Column Validation in 2010

Tags: 2010, column

I need to use a column to capture ID numbers.  I need a way to ensure that the answers entered are only numbers and exactly 12 digits in length.  I've tried a zillion different formulas but keep getting syntax errors.  Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is the type of field?

Comment: Single line of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below formula:

```
=IF(LEN([FieldName])=12,ISNUMBER([FieldName]+0),FALSE)
```

**Note**:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (I am not sure but it is based on something language on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).

Comment: Awesome!  Yeah, the semicolon didn't work but the comma did.  Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Welcome, Please upvote and accept if it helped you.